# How to refresh SVG Charts in react native

Tags: react-native, charts, react-chartjs

I integrated SVG charts in my react native project. AT initialization time its working but when data is coming from server and i am trying to update chart its not working.

I tried this link : https://github.com/julienkermarec/react-native-line-chart

```
<LineChart onPressItem={this.selectChart} animated={true} animationDuration={10} height={50} width={this.getChartWidth()} chart={this.state.chart} />
```

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

**First**

Create **ref** above your render function

```
let ref = React.createRef();
return (
    <StyleProvider style={getTheme(material)}>
```

**Second**

Set that ref to your LineChart component

```
<LineChart
    ref={ref}
    // some attrs... 
</LineChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

use state variable for live data:

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
```

so whenever use setData and data change the line chart component will be re-renader.